# Loop for pandas columns

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I want to apply kruskal test for several columns. I do as bellow

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy 
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(9), 'b':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3], 'group':['a', 'b', 'c']*3})
```

and then the Loop

```
groups = {}
res = []
for grp in df['group'].unique():
    for column in df[[0, 1]]:
        groups[grp] = df[column][df['group']==grp].values
    args = groups.values()
g = scipy.stats.kruskal(*args)
res.append(g)
print (res)
```

I get

```
[KruskalResult(statistic=8.0000000000000036, pvalue=0.018315638888734137)]
```

But i want

```
[KruskalResult(statistic=0.80000000000000071, pvalue=0.67032004603563911)]
[KruskalResult(statistic=8.0000000000000036, pvalue=0.018315638888734137)]
```

Where is my mistake?

for a single column i do as below

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers':range(9), 'group':['a', 'b', 'c']*3})
groups = {}
for grp in df['group'].unique():
    groups[grp] = df['numbers'][df['group']==grp].values
print(groups)
args = groups.values()
scipy.stats.kruskal(*args)
```

Comment: How do you compute your missing value by hand?

Comment: sorry, i did not stood the question

Comment: How do you find [KruskalResult(statistic=0.80000000000000071, pvalue=0.67032004603563911)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loops are upside down: the one-column algorithm is your loop invariant with regards to the column you chose. So the column for loop must be the outer loop. In plain English "for each column apply the kruskal algorithm which consists of this group.unique for loop:

```
groups = {}
res = []
for column in df[[0, 1]]:
    for grp in df['group'].unique():
        groups[grp] = df[column][df['group']==grp].values
    args = groups.values()
    g = scipy.stats.kruskal(*args)
    res.append(g)
print (res)
```

Answer (score 0):

before i made like this

```
groups = {}
res = []
for column in df[[0, 1]]:
    for grp in df['group'].unique():
        groups[grp] = df[column][df['group']==grp].values
    args = groups.values()
g = scipy.stats.kruskal(*args)
res.append(g)
print (res)
```

and i get

```
[KruskalResult(statistic=8.0000000000000036, pvalue=0.018315638888734137)]
```

The problem was in indent (((